# How to convert boost::filesystem::path with ".." (go up) components to proper path

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

How to convert a boost::filesystem::path in a form of:

root/subdir1/subdir2/../some.file

to:

root/subdir1/some.file

with possibly multiple "go level up" operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [canonical](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical) from the Boost filesystem library.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need but problem is "which must exist" part. I want to be able to convert a path first, then modify additionally and only then try to open a file / check if exists. (This is my first question on SO so not sure where I should add this comment)

Comment: If the path doesn't exist then you will need to use some string manipulation like @ArneMertz suggests before creating the boost path object.  I would suggest you elaborate on your question with an example to get a better answer.

Comment: I actually am now doing it manually by iterating path "components" (via path::begin()/end()) and popping last component if current component is "..". This actually works but I was wondering if there was a support from boost::filesystem directly. I am accepting your answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

Short question, short answer:

By subsequently simply erasing every `/<dirname>/..` occurence from the path. You could easily use regex for that.

Comment: How would removing "/.." cause to go "one level up"? In my example this would wrongly create root/subdir1/subdir2/some.file

Comment: sorry, didn't realize that `<dirname>` is not shown by SO. edited it, so removing the `/..` and the `/<dirname>` before that will cancel the level up/level down

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the branch_path() ? It returns the parent directory of a boost::filesystem::path

Example:

```
 boost::filesystem::path path("root/subdir1/subdir2/some.file");
 boost::filesystem::path parent = path.branch_path().branch_path(); // "root/subdir1"
 boost::filesystem::copy(path, parent);
 boost::filesystem::remove(path.branch_path());
```

You can use it whatever you like.